# Is there a better way to create a string based enum in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying to create a string based enum in Typescript where I can map from the enum key to enum value. For instance, `Vehicle.car` should be a string like `'Models.Vehicle.Car'`.

I found an approach that works, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct solution. The solution relies on calling a "dummy" function to create the type that I need. I'm wondering if there's any way to create this type without calling a dummy function.

I'm also looking for a solution that avoids repeating the keys and/or value mappings.

Here is the code:

```
//Creates a type which has keys equal to the values of the passed object
function values<T extends string>(obj: { [key: string]: T }): {[K in T]: T} {
  return undefined;
}

export const Vehicle = {
  car: 'Models.Vehicle.Car',
  bus: 'Models.Vehicle.Bus'
};
const vehicle = values(Vehicle); //Creates a temporary type with keys equal to the values in Vehicle
export type Vehicle = keyof typeof vehicle; //Creates a type like ('Vehicle.Car' | 'Vehicle.Bus')

const v: Vehicle = Vehicle.car; //v equals 'Vehicle.Car'
```

Comment: That's seems overly complicated for no reason, may i ask what is the use case ?

Comment: My current use case is that a backend API I'm connecting to uses very long and verbose string enum values. It's possible to model them as a union type in Typescript ('a...' | 'b...' | 'c...' | 'd...'), but I don't like having those big ugly values all over the code. Also, I'd like to be able to do quick refactorings if a value changes, which this approach solves nicely.